# Adding another jsPsych experiment into current/main experiment

Tags: javascript, jspsych

I have a jsPsych experiment and when that experiment ends, I want another experiment (which is present in a separate folder) to run. I want to make sure this transition occurs smoothly and I have timelines of both the experiments at the end.

For example, let us say 'main' is the primary experiment. Once this experiment completes, I also want the participants to do the Digit Span experiment. Now I have the digit span experiment already coded out in a separate folder. I want to integrate it into my existing experiment such that I don't have to duplicate the code again.

I was trying to achieve this using the 'jspsych-external-html' plugin, but it seems that this plugin only allows us to load static HTML pages (mostly used for providing consent forms).
When I used this, I couldn't figure out how to make sure that the jspsych experiment defined in digitspan.html file (under Digit Span Experiment folder) runs and we see that experiment while taking the main experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use JATOS (jatos.org) and build a study out of several components. Each component is basically its own webpage. You can put your 'main' experiment in one component and the 'Digit Span experiment' in a second component. [Here](https://www.jatos.org/Adapt-pre-written-code-to-run-it-in-JATOS.html) is more information about adapting your existing code to JATOS.